# Ant crawling back along the prism edges

Tags: probability, logic, combinations

An ant starts to crawl along the edge of the  prism from vertex A randomly to one of the next three vertices, and continues this for random crawling for the next step.

Question:  What is the probability for the ant  to crawl back to its initial vertex A after 4 of such  steps?

For clarification,  paths similar to A $\to$ B $\to$D $\to$ E $\to$A, A $\to$ B $\to$A $\to$ B $\to$A ,  A$\to$ B $\to$C $\to$ B $\to$A are all valid returns.

The is similar to ([Logic question: Ant walking a cube](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/logic-question-ant-walking-a-cube)), but not the same in the sense that the prism is not symmetrical in all directions which adds quite some  (if not significant) complexities, and the question is also in different scenario - this ant crawls back.

[image]

Comment: Could you simply write the 6x6 transition matrix and raise it to the 4th power?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It should work out through Markov chain concept. I like @user60016 's answer too, it gives a nice thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the possible locations of the ant after the first two moves. The ant can be on vertex A in 3 path(A->D->A,A->C->A,A->B->A), on vertex B in 1 path(A->C->B), on vertex C in 1 path(A->B->C), vertex E in 2 paths(A->D->E,A->B->E), vertex F in 2 paths(A->D->F,A->C->F) and D in 0 paths.

Now we do the reverse: from the above vertices back to A, in two moves. For each vertex, the possible paths would just be the paths of the first two moves in reverse order(for Ex: from vertex E back to A would correspond to E->D->A, E->B->A).

The require probability is $\frac{3^2+1^2+1^2+2^2+2^2}{3^4}=\frac{19}{81}$